# Update two dimensional array using useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array, react-hooks

I want to update my 2d array with **useState**.
It looks like:

```
[[null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null], ...n]
```

You can imagine the array as *rows* and *columns*. Each column has the same value (**null**).

What I want is to assign the value I want to the first element of that 2d array every time a function is called.

1. (First invoke): [[myValue, null, null, null], ...n]
2. (Second invoke): [[myValue, myValue, null, null], ...n]
3. (Third invoke): [[myValue, myValue, myValue, null], ...n]
4. (Fourth invoke) [[myValue, myValue, myValue, myValue], [myValue,null,null,null] ...n]

I tried several ways to do this but unfortunately without success. I will share the code below.
What is the shortest way to do this?

The code I tried:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState(
    Array.from({ length: 6 }, (v) => Array.from({ length: 5 }, (v) => null))
  );
      const addFunc = (e) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
    
        // first way
        setData(
          data.map(([...row]) => {
            row.map((col) => {
              if (col === null) {
                return [...row, [...col, value]];
              }
            });
          })
        );
    
        // second way
        setData((val) => {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (var z = 0; z < data[i].length; z++) {
              if (data[i][z] == null) {
                return [...val, (val[i][z] = value)];
              }
            }
          }
        });
      };
```

Comment: you don't return the value in the first  map function ---> here:  data.map(([...row]) => {

Comment: What is `row` in your code? The first `.map` callback signature doesn't look quite right. You also are not returning any mapped values from that callback. Is your question how to "increment" the row and column for each time the `addFunc` function is called, and update *that* row & column's value?

Comment: I'm sorry my english is not good. actually there is no row or column, I just used the data in the state to better analyze it. exactly what I want is to assign a value to the first element of the first element of the two-dimensional array each time the addFunc function is called, and to assign a value to the second element when the function is called a second time.

Comment: What if the `addFunc` is called a third time? Fourth? Nth?

Comment: Example (First invoke): [[myValue, null, null, null], ...n]
Example (Second invoke): [[myValue, myValue, null, null], ...n]
Example (Third invoke): [[myValue, myValue, myValue, null], ...n]
Example (Fourth invoke): [[myValue, myValue, myValue, myValue], [myValue,null,null,null] ...n]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. I'm just learning how to ask the right questions, because I'm new here, sorry.

Comment: Architecture is pretty weird - you don't want to nest state like that. Use multiple instances of `useState` and your application will be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it sounds like you want to effectively "iterate" through the 2-d array `data` I suggest keeping a "count" or some current "index" value that is incremented each update. Create a utility function that converts this "count" into a computed "row" and "column" index that you want to update.

Example:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [data, setData] = useState(Array(6).fill(Array(5).fill(null)));

const countToRowCol = (count) => {
  return {
    row: Math.floor(count / 5), // 5 is the inner array length
    col: count % 5
  };
};

const addFunc = () => {
  setData((data) =>
    data.map((row, i) =>
      i === countToRowCol(count).row
        ? row.map((el, j) => (j === countToRowCol(count).col ? myValue : el))
        : row
    )
  );
  setCount((c) => c + 1);
};
```

`addFunc` is just mapping the previous state's arrays into new array references for the matching row/column index, otherwise just shallow copies the previous state.

[image: Edit update-two-dimensional-array-using-usestate]

[image]